# How to transfer two value from a single drop down selection

Tags: php, html

I want to transfer two numbers if one chooses a value from a drop-down.

And I want to show the second vale next to that drop-down.

For Example , if one choose option "A" it should show "A" in the drop-down , and "B" near it (out side drop-down menu).

if one choose option "C" it should show "C" in the drop-down , and "D" near it (out side drop-down menu).

It should also transfer that value with it when the form submits.

in short if some one choose "A" , both "A" and "B" should transfer to the net page.

```
echo'
<form id="main_form" name="main_form" method="post" action="options.php">

<select id="main_select" name="main_select">
<option value="A">A</option> 
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="E">E</option>
<option value="G">G</option>
<option value="I">I</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" id="main_submit" name="main_submit" value="submit" />
</form>';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You haven't shown us the code that you have tried to use to make this happen.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I spend 10 minutes to create the code posted here , and I have no idea how to take the next step , that is why I am here. If I have the code , why should I come here ?

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is not a "write my code please" service.  Spend a few hours, then come back with some things that you've tried.  (I don't post a question here until I've spent several hours doing my research).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is probably best achieved with [jquery](https://jquery.com/)

Let me get you started...

Make a div in your html:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Then do something like this in your jQuery script:

```
$('#main_select').on('change', function (e) {
    var option_selected = $("option:selected", this);
    var value_of_selected = this.value;
    $(value_of_selected).appendTo('#content');
});
```

Since you know PHP you should be able to monkey around with the jQuery to achieve what you need.